# Pass variable value between screens

Tags: flutter, dart

I wrote an example code, it is unfortunately large, but this is the only way to understand the essence of my problem.

On page B, in class B, there is the following code -

```
class B extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  var result = '';
                  var url = "http://10.0.101.141:6113/api/Cashier/authenticate";
                  final response = await http.post(
                    Uri.parse(url),
                    headers: <String, String>{
                      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                    },
                    body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
                      'login': _textEditingController.text,
                      'password': _passEditingController.text
                    }),
                  );
                  if(response.statusCode == 200) {
                    result = jsonEncode(response.body); //THIS VARIABLE I NEED HOW TO DRAG TO FILE "A"
                    print(result);
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/home');
                  } else {
                    print('err');
                  }

                  //
                  // print(_textEditingController.text);
                  // print(_passEditingController.text);
                },
                child: Text('sdfsdfs'))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    )
  }
}
```

I need to use result variable in File A, with class A -

```
class A extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  var sum = int.parse(text);
                  const url = "http://10.0.101.141:6113/api/transaction/createtransaction";
                  final token = ''; //HERE I NEED TO USE THIS VARIABLE
                  try {
                    final response = await http.post (
                        Uri.parse(url),
                        headers: <String, String>{
                          "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
                          "Authorization": 'Bearer $token'
                        },
                        body: jsonEncode(<String, int> {
                          'amount': sum
                        })
                    );
                    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                      Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new Qr()));
                      var res = await response.body;
                      print(res);
                    } else{
                      var res = response.statusCode;
                      print(res);
                    }
                  } catch (error) {
                    print(error);
                  }
                },
                child: Text('sdfsdfs'))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    )
  }
}
```

Can you please tell me how can I do this? I tried to provide all the necessary information, sorry if there is a lot of unnecessary code, I just sketched this small construction, but it conveys the essence of the problem

Any help will be glad!

PS: By the [link](https://dpaste.org/FahsQ) you can see the code of two files, where there are exclamation marks, this variable needs to be moved to where the question marks

Answer (score 0):

You can send like this

```
class B extends StatelessWidget {
  const B({ Key key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(child: TextButton(onPressed: (){
      Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new A(value: "My value",)));
                     
    }, child: Text("Send second class")),
      
    );
  }
}


class A extends StatefulWidget {
    A({Key key, this.value}) : super(key: key);
  final String value;
  @override
  State<A> createState() => _AState();
}

class _AState extends State<A> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(child: Text(widget.value),);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! And could you tell me where exactly the class _AState should be?

Comment: And I can't use "const" in "const B({..."

Comment: And - The named parameter 'value' isn't defined. (Documentation)  Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'value'. (Class B)

Comment: you have to convert statelesswidget  to statefulwidget. and use widget.value instead of value

Comment: `Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new A(value: "My value",)));` asks for a key. What will he be?

Comment: what ever you want. sample: A(value: token,)